# KubeMQ Omits Acks / Acknowledgements From Streams

Tags: events, apache-kafka, event-handling, eda

This functionality:

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#acks

seems to be missing from KubeMQ streams. Are we missing something or have they just omitted it? This would fundamentally change our architectural decisions in choosing an event driven model. Or perhaps we're missing a new way/terminology of guaranteed once delivery using events and persistence with KubeMQ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. KubeMQ is not the same as Kafka Streams; the later being a Kafka only client library. I assume you meant to link to the Producer config page directly. Not all messaging systems support acknowledgments. No messaging system is truly 100% guaranteed delivery. The Kafka target does have acks. Source: https://github.com/kubemq-io/kubemq-targets/blob/master/targets/messaging/kafka/client.go#L40

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Perhaps we are being a little naieve. How would you use kubemq for microservice communication where you need best assurance that messages are delivered at least once? Which kmq pattern? Thanks

Comment: I've not used kubemq. I'm only responding with reference to the kafka tag. Perhaps you'll get a more direct answer using their community slack

Answer (score 0):

> guaranteed once delivery using events and persistence with KubeMQ

According to the docs, that's not (currently?) possible

> support for  **At Most Once Delivery** and **At Least Once Delivery models**

https://docs.kubemq.io/

If you want to run a Kafka broker in Kubernetes, instead, you can look into the Strimzi Operator, as one example.